# select and create checkbox list in php itself

Tags: php, html, mysql, checkbox

I have written php code to generate dynamic checkbox list.I want to accept that checkbox checked value and use it furthur to display another checkbox list in php itself.

//Here's the code...

```
<?php
    $db_value   = $_POST['database'];

    if($db_select = mysqli_select_db($conn,$db_value)) {
        echo "selected database ".$db_value."\n";
    }
    echo "<br>";

    echo "\n"." Select Tables : ";

    $table  = "show tables from $db_value";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$table);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        echo "<br>";
        echo "<input type='checkbox' name='checklist[]' value='{$row[0]}'>{$row[0]}</input>";
    }
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<input type='submit' value='validate' name='ok'>";
?>
```

I want to accept name='ok' and print another checkbox using php. How can I do it?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want to implement here. You want to render a checkbox as checked?

Comment: Yes Gohn67. I want to use the value of submit button in php itself? how shall i go to acheive it?

Comment: What do you mean use the value of submit button in php itself?

Comment: Once the form is submitted, check your `$_POST` variable. There should be something named `$_POST['ok']`. If you click submit button, then the value of `$_POST['ok']` should be `validate`. `ok` is the name of your submit button.

Comment: I am creating a form in php itself. so how can i post the value of submit button?  Can I use <form> ... </form> tags inside php and post the value of submit button to same file?

Comment: Yes, you can't get the POST value until you submit the form back to PHP to handle. Your submit button's value is hardcoded. It's not a dynamic value. Yes, you can use form tags in php. You may need to read more tutorials to gain a better understanding.